# Devise múltiplas páginas de login!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4, devise

estou utilizando Devise para efetuar minha autenticação. Porém tenho 3 tipos de perfil, e criei através do comando `rails g devise MODEL` meus usuários (Admim, dev e gerente), mas o Devise criou uma página de login para cada tipo de perfil, gostaria de unificar e fazer login utilizando somente uma página!.

Minha ideia é criar uma view pegando o e-mail e a senha e repassar para um controlador Custom herdando de **`Devise::Sessions`** e sobrescrever o método que efetua o Login, buscando o e-mail nas 3 tabelas e redirecionando o usuário para Controlador responsável pelo perfil dele.

Como eu poderia fazer esse "login manual" com Devise? Alguma outra solução para isso?

Comment: Você não poderia fazer um autenticação única e fazer esse direcionamento dependendo da responsabilidade de cada ator no sistema? Ou seja, você usara um unico modelo que pode ser admin, dev ou gerente.

Answer (score 1):

Uma estratégia que eu uso é criar um model `User` (responsável pela autenticação) e um model `Profile` que contém os dados do perfil. Então você faz um relacionamento entre `User has_one Profile` e em `Profile` você adiciona um campo `kind` com o tipo do perfil (`admin`, `dev`, `gerente`).

A partir daí é só regra de negócio e puxar o relacionamento. Espero que tenha ficado claro.